# Meta boxes disappearing in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a functionality to add some metaboxes to a post.
I am having an issue with the boxes displayed in the image attached. My client is complaining that for some reason in any random moment the metaboxes disappear and all the information on them, like some body pressed Remove and save the post.

[image]

This is the code that I am using to save and update the metaboxes:

```
//Save product price
add_action('save_post', 'save_detailss');

function save_detailss($post_id){ 
global $post;

 // to prevent metadata when the post is saved on the Quick Edit mode
if (wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_inline_edit'], 'inlineeditnonce'))
return;

// to prevent metadata or custom fields from disappearing
if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
return $post_id; 

if (isset($_POST['more_info_data'])){
    $data = $_POST['more_info_data'];
    update_post_meta($post_id,'more_info_data',$data);
}else{
    delete_post_meta($post_id,'more_info_data');
}
}
```

- Is that I am missing something?
- how can I find out why this is happening, is there any way to track the cause of the problem?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Your logic is incorrect on the verify nonce.  Don't you want it to be if the nonce **is not** verified, do a return?

Comment: oww i see... what you mean... I'll change that. Do you know any way to track when the remove is occurring ?  thanks so much

Comment: I don't think the *meta box* is being removed.  I'd guess the *event details* got removed.  Meta boxes are added via PHP, while the "remove" for event details looks ajaxy.

Comment: Yeah they are added via js. And removed via js, the problem is that my client says that they have been automatically disappearing without pressing any button.

Comment: "They are added via js"... what are? The meta boxes? That's the wrong way.  That's why they are getting removed.  You need to add the meta boxes using the WP [meta box](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) architecture.

Comment: I'd like to help, but need you to help me help you: 1) You keep using the word "they".  Please be specific -  instead of "they", use the specific term: meta boxes? events?  2) Also, in order to help, you need to show the code here that adds the metaboxes.